# How to write a series of float from text using fstream

Tags: c++, floating-point, operator-keyword, fstream

Example ABC.txt
10.f 30.2f 20.f

I want to retrieve those information and store inside my array. However i am unsure how to do it.

I dont understand what is 
Then (if good), it calls num_get::get (using the stream's selected locale) to perform both the extraction and the parsing operations, adjusting the stream's internal state flags accordingly. Finally, it destroys the sentry object before returning.

```
std::fstream filestr("ABC.txt", std::fstream::in);

if(!filestr.good()) //Logical error on i/o operation
{
  //Unable to process
  filestr.close();
  return;
}

unsigned index= 0;
unsigned count= 0;


while(filestr.good())
{
  float buffer= 0.f;
  filestr >> std::skipws >> buffer;
  score[index]= buffer;
  ++index;
}
filestr.close();
```

Comment: Does your file include the .f on each number? All you need is the number. Also, standard containers have an iterator pair version of their constructor and `assign` function that basically does what you do here (starting from `unsigned index= 0;`), but in one line.

Comment: Hi, what you mean standard containers have an iterator pair version of their constructor and assign function that basically does what you do here (starting from unsigned index= 0;), but in one line?

Comment: The answer just posted shows what I mean. There's also an `assign` function in case you've already created your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. One way is using stringstreams, in combination with vectors and strings:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream filestr("C:\\nums.txt", std::fstream::in);
    std::vector<double> numbers;

    if (!(filestr.good())) {
        std::cout << "BAD FILE" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        std::string temp;
        double d = 0.0;

        while(std::getline(filestr, temp)) {
        std::istringstream iss(temp);

        while(std::getline(iss, temp, ' ')) {
            std::istringstream ist(temp);

            ist >> f;
            numbers.push_back(f);
        }
    }
    }

    //see that the vector has information in it
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
    }
    filestr.close();

    return 0;
}
```

One thing to note is that you could also use iterators here, but that's something you could implement for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple with istream_iterator.  There is only one tricky bit in the code below. The vector constructor call needs an extra set of parens around the first argument to avoid the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

```
#include <fstream>                                                                                                        
#include <iostream>                                                                                                       
#include <iterator>                                                                                                       
#include <vector>                                                                                                         
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                      

using namespace std;                                                                                                      

int                                                                                                                       
main (int argc, char** argv)                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                         
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {                                                                                      
        ifstream in (argv[i]);                                                                                            
        if (!in) {                                                                                                        
            cerr << "Failed to open " << argv[i] << endl;                                                                 
            continue;                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                 
        vector<double> nums ((istream_iterator<double> (in)), istream_iterator<double> ());                               
        copy (nums.begin (), nums.end (), ostream_iterator<double> (cout, "\n"));                                         
    }                                                                                                                     
    return 0;                                                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank I will istream_iterator method.